# How to create an FTP Connection in LINQPad

Tags: c#, ftp, linqpad, ftps, fluentftp

I want to create an FTP or FTPS connection with LINQPad to an FTP/FTPS Server.

I do have the servername and the user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) nuget package and import the following namespaces:

```cs
FluentFTP
System.Net
```

```cs
using (var client = new FtpClient("SERVERNAME"))
{
    client.Port = 990;
    client.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Implicit;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"USERNAME", @"PASSWORD");

    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(cts.Token);
        client.GetListing("/").Dump();
        await client.DisconnectAsync(cts.Token);
    }
}
```